# Use pivot_wider to expand items by response options

Tags: r, tidyr

I´m working with an exam, and I´m trying to get the point-biserial correlation of each response option of each item with the total score of the test.

To do so, I thought of using pivot wider, so I could extend from something like this:

```
math_exam=data.frame(item1=c("a","b","a","c","d"),item2=c("b","b","c","c","a"))

  item1 item2 item3

1     a     b     b
2     b     b     c
3     a     c     a
4     c     c     c
5     d     a     d
```

Into something more like this:

```
      item1.a item1.b item1.c item1.d item2.a item2.b item2.c item2.d
1       1       0       0       0       0       1       0       0
2       0       1       0       0       0       1       0       0
3       1       0       0       0       0       0       1       0
4       0       0       1       0       0       0       1       0
5       0       0       0       1       1       0       0       0
```

If you could recommend any solution either with pivot_longer or any other tool, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably too convoluted but you can try :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

math_exam %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -row) %>%
  mutate(val = 1) %>% 
  group_by(row) %>%
  complete(name, value, fill = list(val = 0)) %>%
  arrange(name, value) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(name, value), values_from = val, 
              names_sep = '.', values_fill = 0) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  arrange(row) %>%
  select(-row)

#  item1.a item1.b item1.c item1.d item2.a item2.b item2.c item2.d
#    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1       1       0       0       0       0       1       0       0
#2       0       1       0       0       0       1       0       0
#3       1       0       0       0       0       0       1       0
#4       0       0       1       0       0       0       1       0
#5       0       0       0       1       1       0       0       0
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data in kind of an awkward shape at first. Better to make it full long, add a bit more info, and then make it wide. For example

```
math_exam %>% 
  pivot_longer(item1:item2) %>% 
  mutate(id=row_number(), ind=1) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(name, value), values_from=ind, values_fill=0)
```

You can remove the `id` column you like with `%>% select(-id)`